# Creating several copies of a google form with names given from spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to create many identical google forms , but each form get it's name from a spreadsheet.
I thought of finding a script that creates the form I made, and every time before I execute the script I am going to change the name with the new name.

Why i am doing this?
I am having a a fleet of power tools , I need to give them QR codes, when the QR code is scanned it opens up a google form which is an inspection checklist after you fill the checklist responses are then saved in  spreadsheets.

Comment: The question has not enough explanation to answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Create Google Form Copies

Here is a way you can create many identical Google Forms using the File.makeCopy(name, destination) method ([see docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(String,Folder))). Add this code to a [container bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script) in your Google Sheet.

```
function copyForm() { 
  const templateFormId = "YOUR_FORM_ID"
  const formsFolderId = "YOUR_FOLDER_ID"

  const templateForm = DriveApp.getFileById(templateFormId)
  const formsFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(formsFolderId)
  const formNames = getFormNamesFromSheet()

  for (let formName of formNames) {
    templateForm.makeCopy(formName, formsFolder)
  }
}

function getFormNamesFromSheet() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"
  const rangeString = "A1:A3"
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName)
  const range = sheet.getRange(rangeString)
  const values = range.getValues()
  const formNames = values.map((item) => { return item[0]})
  return formNames
}
```

## An Alternative Approach: Using QR Codes and Pre-filled forms

Feel free to use copies of your Google Form, but it may be hard to organize all of those files and view data from all the forms in one view. You could instead use one form that has an extra ID field to differentiate between submissions. You can then create many different QR codes that link to same form but pre-fill the ID field differently for each QR code.

Build your form, then click the three dots in the upper right > Get pre-filled link. Update your ID field with some value and click Get link. You'll get something like this: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScjwHZt7FAv8ghHK5G0KQH2k91ozMD4zr4Q9rw5_rFpoIGRhQ/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.71316734=asdf

Look at the end of the link where it says &entry.(some numbers)=(your pre-filled value), in my case &entry.71316734=asdf. You can just create a copy of this link but change the value ("asdf") to some unique id. Once you have all the links you need, you can create separate QR codes for each link, which end up all pointing to the same form, but fill in the id field differently. Then you'll only need one form and all the data will be visible in one table. It's much easier to filter one big table than to combine lots of smaller tables from different Google Sheets.